# WAV audio format is not working on HTML5 page

Tags: html, html5-audio

I need to use a .wav format audio in my HTML code. I used the following code and test it on chrome.

```
<audio controls controlsList="nodownload"><source src="sample.wav" type="audio/wav"></audio>
```

But it's showing an empty audio file on my webpage over and over again and my chrome browser telling me to download that .wav file. How to solve that problem?

Comment: I put your snippet into my Html body and it worked... Make sure your .wav file can be found and is playable at all. Also, try other .wav files to check if the file causing the conflict.

Comment: In the Chrome browser address bar, put the direct HTTP link to the WAV file... Does it play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snippet works well, you can test it here (I made a copy and paste from your post)
http://87.106.127.248/wav.html

Use only well known combinations of sample rate/bit depth, i.e. 44.100/16 bit with browsers

Answer (score 0):

For streaming purposes on the web (like in an `audio` tag)  you should create copies of your audio file in `.mp3` and `.ogg` format and use these for your website.

Then a typical audio tag which could be handled by practically all modern browsers would look like this:

```
<audio>
  <source src="path/to/yourfile.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="path/to/yourfile.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: But actually fact is WAV format is must needed for a research purpose. Fact is not using alternative format like MP3. I can easily use MP3 in that case. But need to use WAV to do a research survey.

Comment: For research you would typically download the wav file which already works the way you have written it in your question.

Comment: BTW, if you only have *one*  file version, you can also put the source info directly into the opening `<audio>` tag as an attribute: `<audio src="path/to/yourfile.wav" controls></audio>`

Comment: I tried it too. But problem is not fixing.